# Accessing PHP extensions within CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Our system uses a program called PDFlib TET for extracting data from PDF files. The software is installed as a PHP extension.

I have the software working fine outside of CakePHP, I can create a new TET object by calling:

```
$tet = new TET();
```

From any file - the extension I am including (php_tet.so) seems to simply work.

However, when I call this from within CakePHP I get the following error:

```
Class 'TET' not found.
```

Is there something basic I am missing here?

Comment: Is your CakePHP app running in the same exact enviorement as a standalone sript you used for testing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jan. The environment was the same on my local machine, the only difference is the folder in which the script resides. Strangely, however, it works just fine on our live server - just not on my own wamp I use for development... I'll keep hunting, although the issue is now resolved I would like to know why it didnt work locally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the extension in the `php.ini` file where you're executing the script. Mind that the command line version of PHP (CLI) uses a different `php.ini` than the webserver by default. E.g. on a recent Ubuntu Linux box, you have to make sure your

```
extension=php_tet.so
```

line is included both in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.